# When a user's question amounts to "write this code for me," what is the best course of action?

Tags: discussion, questions, code

When processing review queues, I often come across questions that amount to, "I need this function to do x, please re-write for me" or "I need code that does this, please provide this code."  Those questions stink to high-heaven for me, but I'm not sure how they are best handled using the review tools.

Is it:

1) downvote the question

--or--

2) flag the question, and if so, with which flag?

--or--

3) some other course of action of which I am unaware?

Should I provide a polite comment in any case?

Comment: Depending on how egregious it is, start at 1 and end at 3 (where 3 is "track down the OP and slap him silly").  For example, a question about how to do something that can be accomplished in a couple lines of code (but that isn't easily solved) may rate a 1, whereas this http://i.stack.imgur.com/bawxD.png rates a 4.